# Is there an easy way to test if "docker build" is needed?

Tags: docker

As some of our `docker build` runs can easily take hours to create the image, is there an easy way to test if the `Dockerfile` will force a partial or complete rebuild? Timestamps alone might not be sufficient as only comments might have changed in the `Dockerfile`, for instance.